# Erro :"Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null' java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver"

Tags: jpa, tomcat, jndi

Olá, estou tentando configurar a conexão com o banco de dados em minha aplicação JPA utilizando JNDI. Estou seguindo esse tutorial (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#PostgreSQL), mas mesmo assim quando eu tento fazer qualquer consulta o sistema dá erro dizendo que não encontrou o driver do banco.
Estou usando o container Tomcat 8, Eclipse, e o Postgres SQL 9.1.

Fiz as seguintes configurações:

1- Diretório lib do tomcat onde coloquei o driver:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2- Arquivo context.xml específico da aplicação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<!-- Deixa a conexão com o banco a cargo do container -->
<Resource name="jdbc/gymclub" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="admin" password="123456" driverclassname="org.postgresql.Driver"
           url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gymclub"/>
</Context>
```

3- web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
 <description>postgreSQL Datasource example</description>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/gymclub</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

4- persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="gymclub">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- Deixa o controle de conexão com o banco a cargo do container. -->
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/gymclub</non-jta-data-source>
    <!-- Habilita cache de segundo nivel <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode> -->
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect" />
        <!-- False no ambiente de produção -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <!-- None no ambiente de produção -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <!-- Essa propriedade permite que as sequences sejam criadas com os valores 
            iniciais que são especificados no domínio. -->
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
        <!-- Cache de segundo nivel do hibernate <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" 
            value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" /> -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Quando eu rodo a aplicação, o tomcat dispara a seguinte exceção:

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2144)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2032)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
```

Alguém sabe como resolver? Já procurei em diversos lugares e não achei solução =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui com a ajuda do @Dilnei Cunha. Fiz as seguintes modificações:

1- O context que eu estava modificando não era o correto, precisei modificar o que fica na pasta Servers do workspace do eclipse. Além disso o nome da propriedade da classe do driver estava incorreto (estava colocando driverclassname quando devia ser driverClassName):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conteúdo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<!-- Deixa a conexão com o banco a cargo do container -->
<Resource name="jdbc/gymclub" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" maxWaitMillis="-1"
           username="admin" password="123456" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
           url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gymclub"/>
```

2- Depois disso ele achou o driver mas deu problema de incompatibilidade. Tive que baixar uma versão mais recente dele:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois dessas mudanças funcionou! @Dilnei Cunha, novamente obrigada pela ajuda! :D

Answer (score 2):

Ola @Giuliana Bezerra,

Adicione a seguinte property:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/gymclub"/>
```

Diga que o tipo de transação é resource local, ex:

```
<persistence-unit name="gymclub" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

Para o Tomcat8 diz na [doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) para por em resource do context um:

```
maxWaitMillis="-1"
```

Comment: Olá @Dilnei Cuha, ainda dá o mesmo erro =/

Comment: Uma coisa que esqueci de comentar mas acho que você já sabe disso é que quando usamos o servidor pela IDE ele cria cache dos arquivos de configuração dentro da workspace ex: C:\Users\dilneicunha\workspace_neon\Servers\Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config

Comment: Isso, estou inclusive mudando apenas eles para que as mudanças afetem apenas a aplicação que estou desenvolvendo e não todas que usam o Tomcat.

Comment: O driver esta apenas na pasta lib do tomcat ou também esta declarado no maven ?

Comment: Está no maven também:                                                           <dependency>
   <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>              </dependency>

Comment: Inclusive, funciona quando eu deixo tudo no persistence.xml. O driver é encontrado direitinho, mas quando precisei mudar pra usar JNDI aí fica dando esse erro do driver =/

Comment: Hummm não sei se isto não da conflito, de uma olhada neste [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found) se por acaso não conseguir me diz que testo aqui.

Comment: Consegui! Vou postar a resposta do que eu precisei fazer, tive que mexer em mais coisas. Vlw @Dilnei Cunha!

Comment: Parabéns Giuliana! embora eu não use mais servlet-container também vou gostar de saber o que faltou :)